# Batch script execution error "%%G was not expected"

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy most recent log file in folder **D:\Temp\ABC_logs** to **D:\Temp\ABC_logs\latest**. Below is the code

```
@echo off

set source=D:\Temp\ABC_logs
set dest=D:\Temp\ABC_logs\latest
pushd "%source%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir *.log /b /a-d /od') do SET newest=%%G

copy "%newest% "%dest%"
popd
```

When I try to execute above code I get an error saying %%G was not expected. Please let me know what could be causing it.

Thanks,
RK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me looks like you've tried to copy the code and directly paste it into the console. You can try :

1) Save the code in batch file and call it.

2) Alter the for loop line like `for /f "tokens=*" %G in ('dir *.log /b /a-d /od') do SET newest=%G`

due to parsing reasons for loops in the batch files needs be with double `%` while in command line they need to be single.

Comment: Might also be an idea to correct `copy "%newest% "%dest%"` to `copy "%newest%" "%dest%"` (missing `"`)

Comment: Also yes there was a missing ". After making both changes the code worked. Thanks to both of you :)

Comment: I also have a additional requirement. My source folder will have files with two different set of file names say LoadPQR_XXXX and PQR_XXXX etc., We want the latest files with names LoadPQR_XXXX and not PQR_XXXX. Do you think this can be achieved making slight changes to code?

Comment: I tried using "LoadPQR*" as below but i got error saying **The system cannot find the file specified ** 
@echo off
set source=D:\Temp\ABC_logs
set dest=D:\Temp\ABC_logs\latest
pushd "%source%"
for /f "tokens="LoadPQR*"" %G in ('dir *.log /b /a-d /od') do SET newest=%G

copy "%newest%" "%dest%"
popd

Comment: @rakshithss - you need to have `loadpqr` either in the directory where your command is executed or in the path variable - https://ss64.com/nt/path.html. And you can use only numbers for tokens in for command - https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: Thanks again! Yes that worked ('dir LoadPQR*.log /b /a-d /od')